# Grouping on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

looks easy but difficult for me. the src/dest path of idx 1, 2, 3 has the same values.
so I need only 1 row for them.

```
idx Src_path           dest_path        code
1   /abc/aaa.txt    /abc/dec_aaa.txt    01
2   /abc/aaa.txt    /abc/dec_aaa.txt    02
3   /abc/aaa.txt    /abc/dec_aaa.txt    03
4   /abc/aaa.txt    /abc2/dec_aaa.txt   04
5   /abc/bbb.txt    /abc2/dec_bbb.txt   01
6   /abc/ccc.txt    /abc2/dec_ccc.txt   01

        the result rows should be like below..  

idx Src_path           dest_path        code
3   /abc/aaa.txt    /abc/dec_aaa.txt    03
4   /abc/aaa.txt    /abc2/dec_aaa.txt   04
5   /abc/bbb.txt    /abc2/dec_bbb.txt   01
6   /abc/ccc.txt    /abc2/dec_ccc.txt   01
```

bit.. difficult for me..

Comment: but they have different _code_.. isn't it?

Comment: Select `MAX(code)` and then use `GROUP BY Src_path, dest_path`.

Comment: yes... they have a diffenent code. I can ignore them the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

naw... kinda lazy you are, but thank god its friday.

```
SELECT MAX(idx), src_path, dest_path, MAX(code) 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY src_path, dest_path
```

should work out.

Answer (score 0):

use `SELECT DISTINCT` Src_path

otherwise you can use

GROUP_CONCAT(Src_path) but then you will have to GROUP_BY